# How to Turn off auto-formatting when surrounding by #region (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, formatting

I dont like the way VS formats the code so, I've unchecked all 3 options in Text Editor / C# / Formatting.
I've also checked 'Ignore spaces in declaration statements'. 
In most cases it works.

But when I'm surrounding code by eg. **#region** I noticed my declarations are reformatted  (Removed TABs)

Is it a way to protect against ??

*I'm using TABs to align, and have checked Tools -> options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> "Keep Tabs"*

Comment: You could avoid using #region's then...

Comment: I'm looking the way how to resolve problem not avoid it...

Answer (score 1):

I use Narrange to format all my files, It reorder methods by name, and group them in regions.
Its very nice.

I post this becuase I like very much the way nArrange formats my code, you can also create your own formats as templates to apply them to your code instead.

but if you prefer to use the Vs internal surround function you can go to to snippes folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#" 
edit the pp_region.snippet file and remove the Enter after the $end clause to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>#region</Title>
      <Shortcut>#region</Shortcut>
      <Description>Code snippet for #region</Description>
      <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>name</ID>
          <ToolTip>Region name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyRegion</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[#region $name$
    $selected$ 
$end$ #endregion]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

and by removing the Enter in the las row of  section Vs will not longer autoformat your code.

Comment: I'm using http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/ butny question was how to turn off default VS behaviour to reformatting code when surounding by region...

Comment: btw did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: No - just leart myself to enter manualy region statements before and after block... :(

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce the problem but I cant, when I surround code using #region #endregion nothing happens.
could it be that rauchy.net/regionerate is the cause of the problem?

Comment: hoo ok, you are using the context menu surround with #region. now i get it.

Comment: ok I just went to the snippets folder and edited the Code section of the #region snipet to look like this
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[#region $name$
  $selected$ 
$end$ #endregion]]>
</Code>

Comment: sorry I cant post the format i used here. the last row of the code section should look like $end$ #endregion]]> in a single row and it should work as you are expecting

Comment: the explanation I find is that the snipped was inserting an Enter to the code it is surrounding and that is triggering the autoformat in VS, by removing the Enter after the $end the autoformat is not being triggered.

Comment: did this worked for you? please see my answer above to get the xml formated as it should be.